# Running 64-bit software on a 32-bit Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, 64-bit, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a [factorio game server](https://www.factorio.com/download-headless) on my raspberry pi 2b. Unfortunately, they only have headless installations of the game for 64 bit operating systems.

I tried running it on Raspbian (which I think is 32 bit) and it refused to run. I also tried running [pi64](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64) but when I wrote the file to the micro SD and booted from it it just loaded the rainbow boot screen and froze on that screen. I tried writing the disk image file with etcher and win32 disk imager and both still had the same problem.

Does anyone know how I could get the headless version of the game to run on a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to run a factorio game server on my raspberry pi 2b.

Factorio only supports the x86 platform.  You cannot run it on an ARM device.

> Does anyone know how I could get the headless version of the game to run on a raspberry pi? thanks in advance.

**If you want to run a 64-bit operating system, which would allow you to run 64-bit software, then you will have to purchase a `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+`.**  The hardware you have currently is not compatible with any 64-bit software.  **What you want is not possible with your current hardware.**  The game of course, cannot be ran on any, ARM device.

> Does anyone know of any other 64-bit raspberry pi operating systems or have any tips of how I can get pi64 to run?

The `ARM Cortex-A7` is a 32-bit ARM processor.  It is not possible to run a 64-bit operating system on the `Raspberry Pi 2b`.  Your processor only supports 32-bit software.  Since it is impossible to run a 64-bit operating system, it is impossible, to run 64-bit software on it.

[image]

> The ARM Cortex-A7 MPCore is a 32-bit microprocessor core licensed by ARM Holdings implementing the ARMv7-A architecture announced in 2011.

Sources:

- [Cortex-A7](https://developer.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a7)
- [ARM Cortex-A7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A7)

Comment: @theReubenator - Please read my answer again.  I have answered your question as it is currently written.

Comment: @theReubenator - Please read my answer again.  I have answered your question as it's currently written.  I feel I have answered all of your questions.  *I am not going to answer any question asked in a comment, if I answer one question, I am afraid you will continue to ask additional questions as a comment.*

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that those server builds mention Windows/Mac/Linux so it is reasonable to assume that they are intended for x86-64 rather than Arm64. A source build would be needed for Arm.

Comment: @Mokubai - The author wants a headless installation which does support Linux.  However, I didn’t even confirm, if the software even supported ARM.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi has an ARM CPU. This means that most games cannot run, because most games are not ported to the ARM platform.

If your game supported ARM, then it *could* work, but bear in mind that the 4B is out there and is much faster than these older generations of Pi, and your RPi 2B has very slow CPU, very slow RAM.